# C Parameter Doesn't Affect Accuracy [LibSVM for string data]

Tags: string, validation, classification, svm, libsvm

I'm working on a protein classification problem with svm, so i use LibSVM for string data. The string kernel defined into LibSVM is the edit distance kernel, it depends from a parameter gamma. During cross-validation, changing C and gamma parameters, i get 75% of accuracy in every way! Moreover, also changing the number of trainingset patterns, i get the same accuracy. I use the SCOP database. I have no idea about this behavior!

Comment: Please do not SHOUT your questions here. There are Shift keys on both sides of your keyboard to make them easier to reach, because properly cased text is much easier to read and understand. Typing your subject in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read, will not help you get an answer faster, and quite frankly is rather annoying and rude. Thanks.

Comment: I'm so sorry, but i didn't understand what you said me about shift keys. Sorry again.

Comment: I mean PLEASE DON'T TYPE YOUR QUESTIONS IN ALL CAPS HERE. :-) The Shift key makes it so you can properly case your text because it's easier to read when it's properly cased. (Use Upper Case where it's appropriate, and don't use it WHERE IT IS NOT.)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the counts of each type of misclassification error. If you are getting a constant error rate like this then it is quite possible that every observation is getting assigned to the same class. For example, if 75% of your training observations are in one class and the classifier assigns every observation to that class, then you'll see an error rate of 25%.

Comment: yes! clear! i have 3/4 of my training set with label -1. So, my svm classify all patterns in -1 class. Thanks very much for this suggestion.

Comment: But if i have this problem with the edit distance kernel, how can i solve it? The only one solution is to change kernel? Or maybe it is unbalanced data problem?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the edit distance kernel in particular but I think that this is more likely to be a data balance problem. Since your imbalance doesn't seem to be too severe, a weighted SVM might do the trick. This is easy to do with libsvm. If you are using R this is done via the `class.weights` parameter of the `svm` function call. If you are using something other than R it shouldn't be too different.